# iphone TabBarController default view

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, storyboard, ios5

I am new to iPhone and building an application which requires tab bar navigation. I am using storyboard to do it that means 5.0 platform. I have a created three viewcontrollers, and did set up the views in storyboards for that as well. The application is showing three tabs at the moment and is switching properly now. 
Now, is the any facility in iPhone to set a default view, so that when the application launches it should show the third view instead of first which it is doing right now?

Answer (score 1):

With code you can do it like below:

```
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];  
   //third view
```

Comment: ok, so where should I do it? I mean which controller? or in appdelegate.m?

Comment: Your tabbar controller probably is in your app delegate. you sholud do it in your app delegate

Comment: ok, so when I put the above code in first view in function viewDidLoad , it worked but..only the tab indicator is set to that tab but not the view...the view is still showing for the first view.